# How does "giving way" in the UK parliament work?

Tags: united-kingdom, parliament

In UK parliamentary debates, an MP from the Government or Opposition gives a speech on the topic (e.g. see [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Sh-4c5XWRM)). Yet, frequently, the person speaking "gives way" to another MP (called "right honorable lady/gentleman") of his/her choice, so that this MP intervenes, sometimes asking a further question to the member speaking. After watching this process several times, it is unclear to me:

- how requests to give way are put forward
- to whom the member speaking decides to give way

All I can find on this "giving way" business is [here](https://www.parliament.uk/site-information/glossary/give-way/), but it does not address the issues above. Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the House of Commons' ["Rules of behaviour and courtesies in the House"](https://www.parliament.uk/documents/rules-of-behaviour.pdf) (December 2015),

> You may intervene briefly in someone else’s speech, but only if the
>   Member who has the floor gives way. If  the Member makes clear that
>   they are not giving way,  you should resume your seat. An intervention
>   should  relate directly to what has just been said and not be a  short
>   speech of its own.

This (and a look at House of Commons' footage) implies that a Member would stand in order to signal that they wish to speak. Hansard (the transcript of debates) also records this by listing, for example "*rose—*" and, as [origimbo notes](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/36041/how-does-giving-way-in-the-uk-parliament-works/36047?noredirect=1#comment139350_36047), on occasion this will be accompanied by a verbal request, e.g. "Will the hon. Gentleman give way?". Examples of both of these can be found in [Hansard](https://hansard.parliament.uk/Commons/2015-07-07/debates/889c004b-fd5c-44fe-9e84-a1886362d948/EducationAndAdoptionBill(SixthSitting)?highlight=give%20way#contribution-15070750000061).

In any case, it is entirely at the discretion of the Member speaking whether or not they give way (or, as the former Shadow Chancellor put it): ["To give way or not to give way, that is the question."](https://hansard.parliament.uk/Commons/2015-03-19/debates/15031925000004/AmendmentOfTheLaw?highlight=give%20way#contribution-15031925000066)

Comment: It's certainly not unknown for another MP to ask directly the one speaking to give way either: https://hansard.parliament.uk/search?searchTerm=give%20way&partial=False